# How to convert a string field to array using Logstash

Tags: logstash

How can I convert a string field to array using Logstash ?

I have a field like below:

```
"language" : "english"
```

I need it to be converted to:

```
"language" : ["english"]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your field *language* is already mapped to a datatype (which usually would be text/keyword), **converting** would cause issues at index time because the array type would not match the text/keyword type.

Notice that due to [dynamic mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-mapping.html), Elasticsearch will automatically create a mapping to text/keyword for the language field (assuming the first indexed value was a String like "english") **even if you haven't set an explicit mapping for that index.**

So depending on your mappings I would suggest to create a new field for that array.

You can do that with the [ruby filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html) like in the following (untested though):

```
filter{
  ruby{
    code => '
      langValue = event.get("language")

      langArray = []
      langArray << langValue

      event.set("name_of_the_new_field", langArray)
    '
  }
}
```

**Code explanation:**

In line #4 you create a variable with the value of the language field. In your example this would be *english*. Please refer to the [Event API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-api.html) for detailed usage.

In line #6 you initialize a new array. In the following line you add the variable with value *english* to that array. Refer to [this page](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1278994&seqNum=3) to get more information about ruby arrays.

Finally in the last line of code you set a new field to the event with the array as its value. Note that the first argument in the paranthesis should be the name of the newly created field.

I hope I could get you some hints/food for thought to solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you! Its working now with the above ruby filter.